# Differing number of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, rbind

Suppose I have a vector of numbers a `a<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` and a vector of positions b `b<-c(1, 2, 3)`.
Then I want to get the numbers that come before every position b in the vector a.
I do this `lapply(b, function(x) a[1:x])` and I get the result

```
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Now I want to combine them in a dataframe normally if the number of values for every position were equal I would have done `t(as.data.frame(lapply(b, function(x) a[1:x]))` But I cannot do that right now because the number of rows are different. How can I put zeros for the non-existing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output `list` is 'lst1', then make the `lengths` same with `length<-` assignment

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {
    length(x) <- max(lengths(lst1))
    replace(x, is.na(x), 0)})
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- lapply(b, function(x) a[1:x])
```